# How to handle an error when loading a picture into a TImage component?

Tags: c++, image, error-handling, c++builder, vcl

I am using a VCL `TImage` component to load a picture from a file in Embarcadero C++Builder 11.3.

"pic.bmp" is a valid picture:

```
Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile("C:\\SomePath\\pic.bmp");
```

This fully works as intended.

However, "pic2.bmp" is a corrupted file:

```
Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile("C:\\SomePath\\pic2.bmp");
```

This displays a message box informing of an error and terminates the rest of the procedure.

What I really want to happen is that the error is caught and a "broken picture" is loaded and displayed in its place.

Code I have tried:

```
Ustr="C:\\SomePath\\pic2.bmp";

try
{
  Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(Ustr);
}
catch (const exception& e)
{ 
  Ustr="C:\\SomePath\\ErrorPicture.png";
  Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(Ustr); 
}
```

Image1 seems to ignore the handling and displays the error message box anyway.

I have tried:

```
Image1->NoErrMsg = true;
```

..in conjunction with the `try`/`catch`. On compiling for a test run, I received a compiler error:

> no member named 'NoErrMsg' in 'Vcl::Extctrls::TImage'

I have also tried:

```
#include <SysUtils.hpp>
...
NoErrMsg = true;
```

But that didn't work.

I am obviously missing something and it is probably simple, but all of my Google-fu returns results on resolving images, not loading. I need to know how to handle a bad image quietly and behind the scenes, without bothering the user with a message box.

Comment: `LoadFromFile` is documented as being able to throw a `EInvalidGraphic` which is a subclass of `System::Sysutils::Exception`. This in turn derives from `TObject`, but crucially **does not inherit from `std::exception` at all.** Try catching a `const System::Sysutils::Exception&` instead.

Comment: Note that `EInvalidGraphic` is not the only `Sysutils::Exception` descendant that `LoadFromFile()` can throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exception` (lowercase `e`) usually refers to the [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) base class (assuming you have a `using` statement somewhere that is pulling `exception` into the calling namespace).  However, that is a C++-specific class, whereas the RTL/VCL is written in Delphi Pascal instead, which uses the [`System::Sysutils::Exception`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Exception) (uppercase `E`) base class for its exceptions.

Remember, C++ is a case-sensitive language!

Since you are not actually catching what `LoadFromFile()` is throwing, that is why you are still seeing the message box.

Try this instead:

```
try
{
  Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(Ustr);
}
catch (const Exception&) // <-- use Exception, not exception!
{ 
  Ustr="C:\\SomePath\\ErrorPicture.png";
  Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(Ustr); 
}
```

Alternatively, fully qualify the class namespace so there is no confusion:

```
catch (const System::Sysutils::Exception&)
```

Alternatively, use a catch-all instead, since you are not doing anything with the `Exception` object (such as logging it, etc):

```
catch (...)
```

---

As for `NoErrMsg`, the compiler is correct, it is not a member of the `TImage` class, it is a global variable in `System.hpp` instead.  But even so, the VCL doesn't actually use it, which is why setting it has no effect in your case.  It is used only by `System::WriteErrorMessage()`, which is called only when a runtime error occurs during app startup or when calling `System::Halt()`.

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!! I figured it was something small, but I looked at this problem for a day and a half with no progress. After a while, It just starts to blend together and make even less sense.

I also very much appreciate the detailed explanation of what was going on with the internals of the TImage component.